# rails has_many_through creates a double join, how to optimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation in which Schools and EventLeg records are tied together through Photos, which belong to a given Event.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :event_leg
  has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
end
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_legs, :through => :photos, :group => 'event_legs.id'
  has_many :photos
end
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
  has_many :events, :through => :photos
  has_many :event_legs, :through => :photos
end
class EventLeg < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_many :schools, :through => :photos
end
```

I need to get the schools that appeared in a given event leg at an event.

```
@event = Event.find 4088
@event.schools.joins(:photos).where('photos.event_leg_id' => 28034)
```

This results in SQL that joins the `photos_schools` table twice, once to `schools` and once to `photos`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `schools`.* FROM `schools` 
INNER JOIN `photos_schools` `photos_schools_join` ON `photos_schools_join`.`school_id` = `schools`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `photos` `photos_schools_2` ON `photos_schools_2`.`id` = `photos_schools_join`.`photo_id` 
INNER JOIN `photos_schools` ON `schools`.`id` = `photos_schools`.`school_id` 
INNER JOIN `photos` ON `photos_schools`.`photo_id` = `photos`.`id` 
WHERE `photos`.`event_id` = 4088 AND `photos`.`event_leg_id` = 28034
```

The second JOIN of photos_schools -> photos is unnecessary, the following query does the same thing and faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `schools`.* FROM `schools` 
INNER JOIN `photos_schools` ON `schools`.`id` = `photos_schools`.`school_id` 
INNER JOIN `photos` ON `photos_schools`.`photo_id` = `photos`.`id` 
WHERE `photos`.`event_id` = 4088 AND photos.event_leg_id = 28034;
```

So why is AR creating this second set of joins, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try skipping the joins(:photos) i guess it should work

```
     @event.schools.where('photos.event_leg_id' => 28034)
```

Comment: yep realized that about 10 minutes after I posted this. In my defense I was up till 4am the night before :)